# ASP.NET BoilerPlate: How to detach entity object from context?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

How to detach entity object from context?

1. Unable to get access to the context in my application service
2. How to clone a row using asp.net boilerplate?
   e.g. I have row say row1 with primary key Id
   I want to insert same row contents with new Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can access DbContext in repository (should not use DbContext in application service). Create custom repository, define some methods that you want to use in application service layer, see document [here](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Repositories#----custom-repository-implementation)
2. To clone object, you can create copy method in the entity class or use AutoMapper.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can inject `IDbContextProvider<TDbContext>` into your class and use it's `GetDbContext` method to get the `DbContext`.

2) If you have a `DTO class` which you use for saving your entity, then for cloning an entity, you can follow below steps:

- Get original entity from database
- Map it to your entity save dto (I assume it does not contain Id field)
- Then map your dto to entity
- Save your entity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use newtonsoft serialization:

```
/// <summary>
/// Perform a deep Copy of the object, using Json as a serialisation method. NOTE: Private members are not cloned using this method.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being copied.</typeparam>
/// <param name="source">The object instance to copy.</param>
/// <returns>The copied object.</returns>
public static T CloneJson<T>(this T source)
{            
    // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
    if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
    {
        return default(T);
    }

    // initialize inner objects individually
    // for example in default constructor some list property initialized with some values,
    // but in 'source' these items are cleaned -
    // without ObjectCreationHandling.Replace default constructor values will be added to result
    var deserializeSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings {ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace};

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source), deserializeSettings);
}
```

Or you can use ObjectCopier

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;

/// <summary>
/// Reference Article http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tips/SerializedObjectCloner.aspx
/// Provides a method for performing a deep copy of an object.
/// Binary Serialization is used to perform the copy.
/// </summary>
public static class ObjectCopier
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Perform a deep Copy of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of object being copied.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="source">The object instance to copy.</param>
    /// <returns>The copied object.</returns>
    public static T Clone<T>(T source)
    {
        if (!typeof(T).IsSerializable)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("The type must be serializable.", "source");
        }

        // Don't serialize a null object, simply return the default for that object
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(source, null))
        {
            return default(T);
        }

        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
        using (stream)
        {
            formatter.Serialize(stream, source);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }
}
```